# Icefaces ACE pie chart SectorSeries class missing

Tags: jsf, charts, icefaces

I tried to implement this example:
 
http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf?grp=aceMenu&exp=chartBean

I wanted to import the

```
org.icefaces.ace.model.chart.SectorSeries
```

class, it isn't in the jar file.

I use maven, and I added this dependency to the project's pom file

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
   <artifactId>icefaces-ace</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Could someone tell me what I do wrong?

I can't find anywhere the location of this class.
Please help me!
Thanks in advancd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that class was not available until version 3.1.0 (not 3.0.1) so you'll need to upgrade your Maven poms to get that release.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was the problem.